# Find the value of t that makes $x^{-t}$ closest to $e^{-x}$ from 0 to infinity

Tags: linear-algebra

Not a homework problem, but I was curious to figure this out until I realized I forgot how.

I think it's something to do with the Graham-Schmidt process and an inner product, but I remember none of this.

Could someone tell me where to start? Thanks!

Comment: Closest in what sense? I assume you mean the L2 distance, i.e. you want to find the value of $t$ which minimizes $\|x^{-t}-e^{-x}\|_2^2 = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}(x^{-t}-e^{-x})^2\,dx$, correct?

Comment: The trouble with this is that $x^{-t}$ is never in $L^2[0,\infty)$, i.e.
$\int_0^\infty x^{-2t}\; dx = \infty$ for all $t$, so the question does not make sense.